# Se envían los datos duplicados a mi base

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código. El problema principal es que los datos se mandan a la base duplicados. No estoy viendo donde está el problema.
adjunto todo el código que tengo de igual manera me lo sigue duplicando en la db

```
$total_general = 0.00;
$cheques = 0.00;
$cheques_a_terceros = 0.00;
$dola = 0.00;
$efectivo = 0.00;
$depositos = 0.00;
$depositos_terceros = 0.00;
$monto_sus = 0.00;
$monto_ganancias = 0.00;
$monto_ing_brutos = 0.00;
$comp_ing_brutos = "";
$monto_iva = 0.00;
$tot_faltante =  0.00;
$tot_gen = 0.00;
$cliente  = 15671;
$fecha_ing = date('Y-m-d'); 
$fecha_ing11 = date('Y-m-d'); 

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
$codpais = 1;
$moneda = 1 ; 
// AGREGO LOS CHEQUES
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert1"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert1"] == "cheque")) {
    // Busco el ultimo nro de la serie para los cheques
    mysqli_select_db($amercado, $database_amercado);
    $query_comprobante = "SELECT * FROM series  WHERE series.codnum =6";
    $comprobante = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_comprobante) or die("ERROR LEYENDO SERIES PARA CHEQUES");
    $row_comprobante = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comprobante);
    $totalRows_comprobante = mysqli_num_rows($comprobante);
  $comprobante = $row_comprobante['tipcomp'];
    $banco          = $_POST['banco'];
    $query_sucursal = "SELECT * FROM sucbancos WHERE codbanco = '$banco'";
    $suc = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_sucursal) or die("ERROR LEYENDO SUCURSALES");
    $row_sucursal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($suc);
    $sucursal = $row_sucursal['codnum'];
    
    $numcheque    = $_POST['numcheque'];
    $vence_cheque = $_POST['venc']; 
    $importe      = $_POST['importe']; 

    $vencimiento  = substr($vence_cheque,6,4)."-".substr($vence_cheque,3,2)."-".substr($vence_cheque,0,2); // TRansformacion del cheque
    $fecha_ingreso = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $estado = "P" ;
    $tcomp =  $_POST['tcomp'];
    $serie = $_POST['serie'];
    $serierel = $_POST['serierel'];
    $tcomprel = $_POST['tcomprel'];
    $numfac = $_POST['numfac']; 
    $codrem = $_POST['codrem'];
    echo $codrem ;
    $num_comp = ($row_comprobante['nroact'])+1 ;
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO cartvalores  (tcomp, serie, ncomp, codban, codsuc, codchq , codpais , importe , fechapago , fechaingr ,  serierel , tcomprel , estado , moneda , ncomprel , codrem ) VALUES ('$tcomp','$serie','$num_comp','$banco','$sucursal','$numcheque' ,'$codpais','$importe','$vencimiento', '$fecha_ingreso' ,'$serierel','$tcomprel' ,'P' ,'$moneda', '$numfac', '$codrem' )";

  var_dump($strSQL);
    $result = mysqli_query($amercado, $strSQL);             
           
    $actualiza = "UPDATE `series` SET `nroact` = '$num_comp' WHERE `series`.`codnum` ='6'" ;    
  
  
    $resultado=mysqli_query($amercado,  $actualiza);

  

}


mysqli_select_db($amercado, $database_amercado);
$query_bancos = "SELECT * FROM bancos";
$bancos = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_bancos) or die("ERROR LEYENDO BANCOS (524)");
$row_bancos = mysqli_num_rows($bancos) > 0 ? mysqli_fetch_assoc($bancos) : "No hay Datos...";
$totalRows_bancos = mysqli_num_rows($bancos);

mysqli_select_db($amercado, $database_amercado);
$query_tipcomp_ret = "SELECT * FROM tipcomp WHERE codafip IS NOT null AND activo = 1";
$tipcomp_ret = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_tipcomp_ret) or die("ERROR LEYENDO RETENCIONES (530)");
$row_tipcomp_ret = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tipcomp_ret) ? NULL : "No hay Datos...";;
$totalRows_tipcomp_ret = mysqli_num_rows($tipcomp_ret);

mysqli_select_db($amercado, $database_amercado);
$query_cabfac = "SELECT * FROM cabfac WHERE cliente = $cliente AND tcomp IN (51,52,53,54,89,92,111,112) AND estado ='P'";
$cabfac = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_cabfac) or die("ERROR LEYENDO CABFAC (536)");
$row_cabfac = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cabfac);
$totalRows_cabfac = mysqli_num_rows($cabfac) ;




mysqli_select_db($amercado, $database_amercado);
$query_rem = "SELECT * FROM remates WHERE codcli = $cliente ORDER BY ncomp DESC";
$rem = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_rem) or die("ERROR LEYENDO  REMATES");
$row_ncomp_rem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rem) ? NULL : "No hay Datos...";
$totalRows_rem = mysqli_num_rows($rem);

$query_Cheques = "SELECT * FROM cartvalores";
$Cheques = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_Cheques) or die("ERROR LEYENDO CARTVALORES 550");
$row_Cheques = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Cheques) ? NULL : "No hay Datos...";;
$totalRows_Cheques = mysqli_num_rows($Cheques);

$query_sucursales = "SELECT * FROM sucbancos";
$sucursales = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_sucursales) or die("ERROR LEYENDO SUCBANCOS 555");
$row_sucursales = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sucursales) ? NULL : "No hay Datos...";;
$totalRows_sucursales = mysqli_num_rows($sucursales);


$tcomprel = "2";
$serierel = "3";
$ncomprel = "33442";
$tot_gen =  "525678.9";
$remate  = "2606";
$codrem  = "2606";
$codrem11  = "2606";




?>




    <form id="cheques" name="cheque_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" >
                <tr>
                   <td width="140"><select name="banco" class="seleccion" id="banco">
                     <option value="" class="phpmaker">Seleccione Banco</option>
                     <?php
                       do {  
                            ?>
                     <option  class="phpmaker" value="<?php echo $row_bancos['codnum']?>"><?php echo $row_bancos['nombre']?></option>
                     <?php
                            } while ($row_bancos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bancos));
                                 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($bancos);
                                  if($rows > 0) {
                                     mysqli_data_seek($bancos, 0);
                                    $row_bancos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bancos);
                                   }
                               ?>
                   </select></td>
                   <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="150"><input name="numcheque" type="text" class="seleccion" id="numcheque" /></td>
                    <td width="97"><div align="right">
                        <input name="venc" type="text" class="seleccion" id="venc" size="11" />
                    </div></td>
                    <td width="24"><a href="javascript:showCal('Calendar3')"><img src="calendar/img.gif" width="20" height="14"  border="0"/></a></td>
                    <td><input name="importe" type="text" class="seleccion" id="importe" size="10" />                </td>
                  </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <input name="codrem"  type="hidden"  value="<?php echo  $remate ?>"/>
                    
                    <input name="serie"     type="hidden"  value="6"/>
                    <input name="numfac"     type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $ncomprel ?>"/>    
                    <input name="serierel"  type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $serierel ?>" />
                    <input name="tcomprel"  type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $tcomprel ?>" />
                  <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td width="150"><input name="estado"    type="hidden"  value="P"/></td>
                  <td width="150"><input name="tcomp"     type="hidden"  value="8"/></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert1" value="cheque">
                  <td colspan="3"><div align="center">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="seleccion" value="Ingresar cheques" />
                  </div></td>
                </tr>
              </form>
```

perdón por esto, no se como evitar el "añade mas detalles"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, rem. Ipsa inventore suscipit accusamus voluptatum earum. Assumenda itaque porro error, quis ut consectetur totam quia et ex labore officia corrupti.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, rem. Ipsa inventore suscipit accusamus voluptatum earum. Assumenda itaque porro error, quis ut consectetur totam quia et ex labore officia corrupti.

Comment: Parece que no has depurado nada. Empieza por depurar los datos que se están insertando, podrían estar llegando duplicados. Si no es eso, entonces el código se estaría ejecutando dos veces o el `UPDATE` estaría activando un TRIGGER en la base de datos que hace una segunda inserción.

Comment: Me fije en la base de datos y está llegando 2 veces el mismo. la verdad no se por que se manda 2 veces, sintácticamente no esta mal, y borre el update, de todas maneras se sigue mandando doble.

Comment: En que tabla se duplican? En **cartvalores** o en **series**??

Comment: se duplican en cartvalores

Comment: No es en la BD donde debes fijarte sino en los datos. ¿Llegan dos veces? Por favor, depurara los datos y dinos que está llegando a ese punto. Explica además que ocurre antes de que los datos lleguen ahí, que procesos se realizan, etc. Imaginemos que usas JavaScript por ejemplo y allí por error el código se envía dos veces. Pero nosotros no somos adivinos ni estamos ante tu pantalla. Sigue el rastro a tu código y encontrarás el problema.

Comment: Ahí pase todo el código, de igual manera me sigue duplicando el dato. gracias desde ya por la ayuda

Comment: Veo que pusiste esto: `var_dump($strSQL);`. ¿Ahora qué ocurre, ves dos veces la salida de `$strSQL`? Otra cosa, considera quitar el *Lorem ipsum...* de la pregunta. ¿Qué sentido tiene en ella?

Comment: Perdón, lo pongo porque no me deja mandar la pregunta por mayor código que descripción. y con respecto al var_dum, es simplemente para copiar el sql y ver la tabla.